# get the values of child nodes with same name

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
<photos items="5">
<path>
http://www.test1.com
</path>
<path>
http://www.test2.com
</path>
<path>
http://www.test3.com
</path>
<path>
http://www.test4.com
</path>
<path>
http://www.test5.com
</path>
</photos>
```

I'm trying to get all the `path` nodes values into a list.

I tried something like this:

```
var nodes = (from n in xdoc.Descendants("photos")
             select n.Elements("path")).ToList();
```

And after using a `foreach` loop I want to store each value of path nodes into a list... But I don't know how? Is there any other easier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
            const string xml = @"
<photos items=""5"">
<path>
http://www.test1.com
</path>
<path>
http://www.test2.com
</path>
<path>
http://www.test3.com
</path>
<path>
http://www.test4.com
</path>
<path>
http://www.test5.com
</path>
</photos>";
            var xdoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var paths = xdoc.Elements("path").Select(p => p.Value);
```

In case the xml comes from a file with above schema, you can `Load` it:

```
        xdoc = XElement.Load("photos.xml");
        var paths = xdoc.Elements("path").Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: @FlorinM, I've put more details on the answer.

Comment: Is there other solution without hard-coding the entire xml part?

Comment: sure, depends on where you store the xml :) Is that an xml file?

Comment: it is an xml file, yes

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
var paths = xdoc.Descendants("photos").Elements("path").Select(p => p.Value);
```

and then

```
foreach( string p in paths)
{
 /// get the urls in some list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("full path to xml file");
List<string> values = xdoc.Root.Elements("path").Select(p => p.Value.Trim()).ToList();
```